# GraphDB loading NCIt into Desktop version via UI from disk

Tags: ontology, graphdb

I want to load the NCI Thesaurus into the free GraphDB Desktop version installed on my laptop. The full NCIT owl file is too big (480 MB) for direct upload via the UI, so I manually split it into 4 files. By copy/pasting the  and  elements to each split and copy/pasting roughly 1/4 of the content into them. Making sure that I do not leave any elements open.

I can load the files into GraphDB via "Import" without any error messages. Yet I do not get the green "successfully imported in Xs" notification. And when I query the repository the result is empty.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can get that NCIt into GraphDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start GraphDB with following parameter -Dgraphdb.workbench.importDirectory=. Afterwards you should be able to see file in GraphDB Workbench tab "Server files", where you could import it.